# Regexp to strip characters after URL in emacs

Tags: regex, emacs

I have a .org file with lines of this sort:

```
*  
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qibla Qibla - Wikipedia, the free
```

as you can see, an asterisk, followed by newline, followed by URL, followed by one space, and then some extraneous useless text that i want to get rid of.

i would like to format this file to this structure:

```
*  
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qibla
```

or, strip all the characters after the end of the URL while maintaining the rest of the structure.

how can i do this in emacs?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you're doing this interactively with query-replace-regexp, try using this regex to string the junk off the end of the URLS:

```
^\(http[^ ]+\).*$
```

Replacement:

> \1

You can get rid of the asterisks easily enough, use this regex and replace with nothing:

> *^J

Use control-Q followed by control-J to enter the newline.

Edit: Or, to do it in one, replace

```
*^J\(http[^ ]+\) .*^J
```

With

> \1^J

Where ^J is a literal newline inserted by typing control-Q followed by control-J.